# .gitattributes: apply attribute to text only

Tags: git, gitlab, gitattributes

I am trying to define `EOL=CRLF` in `.gitattributes` within a GitLabs instance, and apply that to text files only. Similar questions have been posted, but they all assume you can write the code as follows:

```
* text=auto
*.filetypeA eol=crlf
```

The issue here is, I have both text and binary files for a given filetype. I need to use git's engine to first determine if the file is text or binary, then apply the attribute ONLY to the text files, while leaving binary files untouched.

I am also working under a number of limitations:

- Some solutions recommend modifying the text behavior in Git core files - I am limited to the contents of my repository. I am unable to modify the core behavior of my gitlabs instance, as it is a corporate system I lack access to.
- My organization does not grant any degree of terminal access - I am limited to edits I can make through the Gitlabs UI

The lowest solution would be to manually identify and list rules for specific files. I am looking/hoping for a more robust solution that will account for future files

Comment: The `.gitattributes` file resides per repo too. The change you need to do is within your own repo only (not even project level). More in the [official docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes)

Comment: @azbarcea Correct; a .gitattributes file will be added to each repository. Worst case scenario, my team needs to create a unique version for each repository, and update it as new files are added. I am hoping to create a static .gitattributes file that can be placed in each repository without edit